# Css - Separate Color Transparents

Tags: css, colors, rgb

Is it possible to define only the color-transparent?
for Example

```html
<h3 class="header">header</h3>
```

```css
h3{
  color:red;
}
.header{
  color:rgba(null,null,null,0.3);/* red 30%*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `opacity: 0.3`

If you want the element to be look like invisible, use the value of 0.

A value of 1 has no transparency.

Answer (score 0):

`RGBa` is working with background only, see the `opacity`:

```
h3 {color: red; opacity: .3}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbk574fu/

Of course, opacity makes the background transparent too, if you need to use background for this element, you have to add a wrapper into HTML and set background image to this wrapper, not to h3 element.

```
<div class=header>
    <h3>headline</h3>
</div>

.header {background: green;}
.header h3 {background: red; opacity: .3}
/* there will be green background and red semi-transparent text */
```